the minimum value of $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d})$ if $a,b,c,d>0$
Given $a,b,c,d>0$, find the minimum possible value of $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d})$.
My attempts:
I first tried $(a+1)(b+1)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b})=a+b+1+\frac{a}{b}+1+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\geq8$ by AM-GM.
Simiarly, we have $(c+1)(d+1)(\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d})\geq8$.
Then I started to think about the three-variable case $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})$ but I got no progress at all.
Thanks for any form of help on this problem.

Desperadoyyd, you should add your efforts and attempts to your question, otherwise your post will be closed very soon.

Desperadoyyd, add more context to your question and I will explain you how I got the minimum $\frac{1024}{27}$.

Desperadoyyd, you should add more context to your question, otherwise I will not tell you how I got the minimum $\frac{1024}{27}$.

Angelo, I see that your $\frac{1024}{27}$ comes from $a=b=c=d=\frac{1}{3}$. I was not able to realize which trick I should use though.

Here is a short answer:
realize that $a+1=a+\frac13+\frac13+\frac13$.
Apply $AM\geqslant GM$ on $a,\frac13,\frac13,\frac13$.
Then get $a+1\geqslant\left(\!\frac{4}{3^{3/4}}\!\right)\!\cdot\!a^{\frac14}$ and multiply cyclically to get $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)\geqslant\left(\!\frac{4^4}{3^3}\!\right)\!\cdot\!(abcd)^{\frac14}$.
Now you can show that $(abcd)^{\frac14}\!\cdot\!(1/a +1/b+1/c+1/d)\geqslant4$
by GM-HM inequality.
From which we get the minimum as $1024/27$.
Equality case can be verified to be $\;a=b=c=d=1/3$.

Put $x = \sqrt[4]{abcd}> 0$, and apply Holder's inequality we have: $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1) \ge \left(\sqrt[4]{1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1}+\sqrt[4]{abcd}\right)^4=\left(1+\sqrt[4]{abcd}\right)^4=(1+x)^4$, and use AM-GM inequality: $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{d} \ge \dfrac{4}{\sqrt[4]{abcd}}=\dfrac{4}{x}\implies (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{d}\right)\ge \dfrac{4(1+x)^4}{x}=f(x)$. From this you have a single variable function that you can find a critical point at $x = \dfrac{1}{3}$ and the minimum value of this function and the original expression occurs at $x = \dfrac{1}{3}=a=b=c=d$.
